# get value of date tag in html without datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, appframework

I'm using intel's app framework so there is no .datepicker method. Here's the code that makes the date widget in my app:

```
<label for="startdate">Start Date:</label>
<input type="date" name="startdate" id="startdate" value="2014-02-05" class="jq-ui-forms">
```

how would I get the selected value using just pure javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with intel's app framework, but how about

`var date = document.getElementById('startdate').value;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `element.value`

So, something like:

```
document.getElementById('startdate').onchange = function () { 
    console.log(this.value) 
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JyhED/)

Answer (score 1):

You get the selected value as string in the `date` property of the element and as a `Date` object in the `valueAsDate` property. See description of [`input`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element) in HTML5 CR.

Which one you use depends on what you are going to do with it. In client-side scripting, you would probably want to use the `Date` object. However, since [support to `type="date"`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime) is limited, you probably need to be prepared to dealing with implementations on which it falls back to `type="text"`, and then you have just the `value` to play with, and you need to parse it to a `Date` value.